# Twitter Bootstrap Modal cache on Microsoft Edge and IE (late versions)

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue using `Twitter Bootstrap modals`, whereby my `ajax calls` are not being updated in my `Bootstrap modals`. They are how ever affecting the database.

For example.

I will submit a new Citizenship, how ever - the modal which displays a list of citizenship's does not reflect this change.

Is there a way to clear the cache or have a nocache flag when lauching the modal or in the controllers?

This is the jQuery method which is called upon clicking a link to populate the modal.

```
$("body").on("click", ".modal-link", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).attr("data-target", "#settings-modal");
     $(this).attr("data-toggle", "modal");
});
```

This is the link which is clicked:

`@Html.ActionLink("Citizenships", "Index", "Citizenships", new {@class = "modal-link",title = ""})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false })` to prevent ActionLinks from being cached. Place it at the end of the document or call it when the document is ready.